# List Protocol Used by Requests Proxies - Python3

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, python-requests, proxies

I have a function that checks if a proxy is active by sending a request to a couple of websites using the **requests** library in Python3. I am trying to determine which protocol is available when the request is made (http, https, socks) but can't figure out how.

Here is the function:

```
import requests

def is_prox(proxy_server):
    proxyDict = {"http": proxy_server,
                 "https": proxy_server,
                 "socks": proxy_server}

    test_site = {"http://www.google.com", "http://whatsmyip.org", "http://www.facebook.com"}
    headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.5) Gecko/20091102 Firefox/3.5.5 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)'}

    for site in test_site:
        try:
            r = requests.get(site, headers=headers, proxies=proxyDict)
            status = r.status_code
            if status is 200:
                print(status)
            else:
                pass
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))


if __name__ == '__main__':
      is_prox("http://149.56.232.18:3128")
```

and the output:

```
$>python3 proxcheck.py
200
```

but I would like the output to read: `200 - http` or `200 - https`, or whichever protocol is being used.

I've tried `requests.utils.getproxies()` and `requests.utils.get_environ_proxies(url)` but that isn't what I'm looking for.

I know that it's a dictionary, but I can't figure out how to list which dictionary element is returning `200`.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: It uses `proxyDict["http"]` for HTTP, `proxyDict["https"]` for HTTPS, etc, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Well I know that is how to call the dict elements, but for instance when **requests** makes a requests thru a given proxy the result is either `200` or `429` depending on how the proxy is configured.  So it may give `200` for `http` and `429` for `socks` or `https` or any other variation. I'm trying to figure out how to tell which service or protocol is returning `200`. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Yes, i see what you mean. I have some ideas about HTTP and HTTPS but i don't know how you would check SOCKS though.

Comment: Actually SOCKS isn't really necessary. This function is part of a SQUID hunter program I'm working on for fun and those are http anyway. I thought it would be nice to add which service protocols are available also lol.

Comment: You could use:`'http://api.ipify.org/?format=json` as `test_site`. Then use a for loop to test for protocols ( SOCKS works too by the way ) . If proxy's ip is in the response ( it's a json response `{'ip':'x.x.x.x'}` ) then the proxy supports that protocol.

Comment: Yes that worked. thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear that. Please consider answering your question, as it could be of use to others as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the suggestions by **t.m.adam** I was able to produce the results I was looking for. Instead of having *requests* iterate through the proxies, I just set a **for** loop to iterate through the dictionary and return the proxies that return *200*.

Here is the updated function with the fixed code:

```
import requests

def is_prox(proxy_server):
    proxyDict = {"http": proxy_server,
                 "https": proxy_server,
                 "socks": proxy_server}

    test_site = "http://api.ipify.org/?format=json"
    headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/'
                             '5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.5) Gecko/'
                             '20091102 Firefox/'
                             '3.5.5 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)'}

    for proxy in proxyDict:
        try:
            r = requests.get(test_site, headers=headers, proxies=proxy)
            status = r.status_code
            if status is 200:
                print(str(status) + " - " + str(proxy.upper())
        except Exception as e:
            pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
      is_prox("http://149.56.232.18:3128")
```

which returns:

```
200 - SOCKS
```